# How to create gdal virtual dataset in Java?

Tags: java, dataset, virtual, gdal

By command line virtual dataset is created like this

`$ gdalbuildvrt allFiles.vrt file1.tif file2.tif file3.tif file4.tif`

and I know there is Java library but how do I create virtual dataset?

I have investigated web site https://gdal.org/java/index.html and used internet search engines but didn't find help.

Comment: You can use [GDAL Java Library](https://gdal.org/api/java/index.html)

Comment: I know that there exists Java library but what I don't know is how to use it to get that virtual dataset.

Comment: @DiegoBorba Can you help me with this?

Comment: I promisse that I will try!

Answer (score 0):

From what I read in the [documentation](https://gdal.org/java/index.html) you can do it this way:

First, you register the drivers:

```java
gdal.AllRegister();
```

> This function should generally be called once at the beginning of the application. - [Class gdal](https://gdal.org/java/org/gdal/gdal/gdal.html#AllRegister())

Then, you use [`gdal.GetDriverByName`](https://gdal.org/java/org/gdal/gdal/gdal.html#GetDriverByName(java.lang.String)) to get the driver and [`Driver.Create`](https://gdal.org/java/org/gdal/gdal/Driver.html#Create(java.lang.String,int,int,int)) to create the dataset:

```java
// Sample dataset
Dataset vrtDataset = gdal.GetDriverByName("VRT").Create("allFiles.vrt", 0, 0, 0, gdalconst.GDT_Unknown);
```

**Note:** You should change the [`GDT_Unknown`](https://gdal.org/java/org/gdal/gdalconst/gdalconstConstants.html#GDT_Unknown) and the size/band values.